# Stereoprojection: Where are 2, 3 and 4 on the Riemann sphere?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, riemannian-geometry

I have no math education and am just curious about math.  So please answer as you might answer a ten year old.

I understand that if you project a beam of light from the point at the top of the Riemann sphere (marked infinity) and angle it down through a point half way up the sphere (let's say the point marked real positive one), the beam continues through that point and strikes the plane the sphere is sitting on at the location of real positive one.

As I understand it, to strike the location of real positive two on the plane, you just need to change the angle of the beam and strike the sphere in a particular location above where you struck it before.  Intuitively, I want to say that two's location on the sphere is halfway between the one point and the infinity point, three is halfway between the two point and infinity point, four is halfawy between the three point and infinity point etc. But I've searched and searched and I can't seem to find a single image showing any integers besides one on the sphere to see if I'm right or wrong.

If the Riemann sphere is used to stereoproject the complex plane, why are none of the numbers above one ever makred on the sphere?  And am I wrong in guessing that each one is located halfway between the last and infinity?  Why or why not?

Please remember to treat me as if I am ten in your answers.  Apologies if I've made any errors in my basic description of stereoprojection.  Please correct me if I have.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) has some nice pictures. You could add some more beams yourself, with integer values.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but can't you lower the beam to get other numbers too?

Comment: @Randall Oh, sorry, yes of course, to get numbers below one (0.5, 0.2883, whatever etc.) you would shine the beam through a point somewhere directly below one.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you.  I think one needs more education in math than I have in order to follow the formulas on the Wikipedia page and add more beams, but this should be useful for others!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Stereographic projection of the x-axis onto the unit circle]

Here's a 2D version. I've drawn several points on the x-axis, as well as the unit circle. A line through the North Pole (the point $(0,1)$ is drawn to each point, and where it intersects the unit circle we get our projection onto the circle.

Note that $0$ on the x-axis goes to the South Pole, and $1$ stays where it is (halfway between the South Pole and the North Pole). What about $2$?

It turns out that if we project the point $x_0$ onto the circle, the angle away from the South Pole equals $2\arctan x_0$. Thus, the point $1$ goes to $2\arctan1=2(45^\circ)=90^\circ$ away from the South Pole, the point $2$ goes to $2\arctan2\approx129^\circ$ away from the South Pole, etc. So this is slightly *less* than the halfway mark of $135^\circ$.

By the way, if we change the setup so that the circle is the same size but sits *on top* of the line, this has the same effect as shrinking the line by a factor of two. So the new formula is $2\arctan\frac{x_0}2$. In this setup, again $0$ is at the bottom, $1$ is $53^\circ$ to the right, and $2$ is on the equator ($90^\circ$ to the right).

Comment: In the setup in the picture, the point $(x_0,0)$ is mapped onto the point $\left(\frac{2x_0}{{x_0}^2+1},\frac{{x_0}^2-1}{{x_0}^2+1}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this example.  I'm a little confused as I was under the impression the Riemann sphere sits on top of the complex plane like in you second example where you said "if we change the setup so that the circle is the same sie but sits *on top* of the line" but then you say if that were the case 2 would lie at the equator.

Comment: It makes you want to know more when you're over ten years old ;). For example, find the formulas indicated in the comments. :)

Comment: @HRW I mean that the _projection_ of 2 lies at the equator. Here's a picture: https://i.imgur.com/h1WTsyx.png

Comment: @HRW I've seen "stereographic projection" used to refer to both versions. They are closely related: doing the first version is the same as shrinking the line by a factor of two and then doing the second version. In symbols: if $p_1$ means the first version of the projection and $p_2$ means the second, then $p_1(x)=p_2(x/2)$. (Try to see why this is! Another thing to think about: What if the sphere _floats_ above the plane by some distance rather than touching it?)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Ahh, thank you for clarifying about meaning the projection of two lying at the equator.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thank you for the clarification--I didn't even realize you could move the sphere up and down and get different projections but of course that makes sense.   Though I assume the relationship between the Riemann sphere and complex plane is fixed, with that sphere sittinig on the plane.  I'm still struggling a little with the rest though.  What do you mean by "shrinking the line?"

Comment: @HRW Look at this image: https://i.imgur.com/UeevQFW.jpg What's the relation between the two lines?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Ahh, of course.  Thank you so much for pointing out what I'm sure is obvious for many but not my novice math brain.  "Shrink the line" by raising the plane.  The distance of the line from north pole to equator-plane is the same as the distance from equator-plane to a plane upon which the sphere sits.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I believe I can see the relationship now to your original drawing.  If the circle in that drawing were instead the Riemann sphere, and was sitting on the plane, the line marked '2' in your drawing would actually be '1' and the line marked '4' would be '2'